# one of the windows in the kitchen is opened to the 5th NE street

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is the sentence "one of the windows in the kitchen is opened to the 5th NE street" correct?
Have you better suggestion?

I want to describe the location of the window.

Comment: "...kitchen opens onto 5th NE Street"

Comment: While @MarvMills is right (+1), it's worth mentioning that this doesn't necessarily mean the window *is* open. Idiomatically, it describes the window's location.

Comment: So you need "one of the windows in the kitchen that open onto 5th NE is open"

Comment: What do you want the sentence to mean?  For example:   "As I watch, *one of the windows in the kitchen is opened to the 5th NE street* by a burglar who then climbs out and runs away."  Is that the kind of thing? We can't say if a sentence is 'correct' if we don't know what it means. Please clarify, thanks.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Thanks. Actually I wanna describe the location of window.

Comment: @user4704857, No problem, I have edited your question to add that information. Please note that 'wanna' is not an accepted abbreviation in English except in very informal writing (tweets, texts and song lyrics for example) or when writing dialog. Please use 'want to'. Thanks.

Comment: You don't say "the" for a named street.  A named street is treated as a "proper name" and gets no article.

Comment: And for named streets it's not "5th NE street" but rather either "NE 5th Street" or "5th Street NE".  (The choice is based on local practice.)

Comment: And it should be "faces" or "opens onto" (though the latter only applies if the window is "operable").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, if there is nothing else that needs to be conveyed, one would use "faces":

> one of the windows in the kitchen faces NE 5th Street

You can also use "opens onto" if, indeed, the window can be opened:

> one of the windows in the kitchen opens onto NE 5th Street

One might also say "one of the windows opens onto a courtyard", if that is indeed the case.  Here, "opens onto" (or perhaps "opens into") would be a better choice than "faces", for aesthetic reasons.  (But for windows not on a courtyard I'd prefer "faces".)

And for named streets it's not "5th NE street" but rather either "NE 5th Street" or "5th Street NE". (The choice is based on local practice.  "NE" tends to be first across much of the US, but significant portions of the US Midwest place "NE" last.)

And note that street names are treated as proper nouns and hence do not receive an article.  Hence it's "faces NE 5th Street" and not "faces the NE 5th Street".

Comment: In the Seattle area, streets run east-west, and avenues run north-south.  Many streets are numbered, as are many avenues.  To reduce confusion, the directional affix (such as "NE") is used before Seattle-area street names, and after Seattle-area avenue names.  For example, "The corner of NE 40th Street and 50th Avenue NE is about [a mile away by car](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/NE+40+St+%26+50+Av+NE+98105/40+Av+NE+%26+NE+50+St) from the corner of NE 50th Street and 40th Avenue NE."

Comment: @Jasper - Yeah, like I said, it's kind of a "local option" thing.  In the Midwest many towns have all four quadrants, so there could be four instances of 123 4th Street and four instances of 123 4th Avenue.  Placing the "directional affix", as you call it, last is like saying "Northeast quadrant" -- it selects which corner of the map you're dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

*One of the windows in the kitchen opens onto 5th Street NE.*

Present simple, because the window *always* opens this way!

Comment: How do you know?   We need more context before answering.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - The direction a window opens cannot change.  Why else mention the direction unless it is to specify its orientation?

Comment: You have changed the sentence from passive to active. The purpose is not to proof-read and change what people write but to understand what they are asking and give an answer. Please refer to the site guidelines: ***Help Center > Asking> What topics can I ask about here?***.  ***..please, don’t ask any questions about the following topics. They are out of scope for this site ... Proofreading ("Is this right?", "Are there any mistakes?"), unless the source of concern is clearly specified*** http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: P.S. Since you answered, the OP has clarified in a comment and I have edited the question accordingly. Therefore your answer now becomes correct. Before, you were just guessing.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - The OP asked for help to express an idea.  I read the material, deduced what the intention was and  made "a better suggestion".  This is what I do with all my answers (don't you ?).  This is not what I call proofraeding!

Comment: I call proofreading what the dictionary says it is, i.e. "...to read and correct mistakes in (a written or printed piece of writing)..." http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proofread

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - In an earlier comment you say *...The purpose is not to proof-read and change what people write but to understand what they are asking and give an answer...*.  This is what I did.  I understood what was being asked (I did not guess - see my first comment above) and I gave an answer.

Comment: Your reply (without the context) was a guess. It is also open to opinion (discouraged on this site). If you doubt that, look at the discussion that has ensued following Rathony's answer (another guess). Could I politely suggest you read through the site tour where it describes the sorts of questions and answers that are suitable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30939/discussion-between-dan-and-chasly-from-uk).

Comment: @chaslyfromUK If you had put "another guess" for my answer to indicate I guessed the purpose of the question and answered, you are wrong. I saw the OP's comment and started to write the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "describe the location of the window", you could just use  use "[***face***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/face)":

> Have the face or front pointing in a specified direction: ‘the house faces due east’

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Or you could use "[***point***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/point)":

> to lie extended, aimed, or turned in a particular direction

[Merriam-Webster]

One of the windows in the kitchen "***faces/points***" to 5th NE street.

Note: Edited after the below comments.

Comment: We don't use *window points* in English. We would say *the window looks out on* or *the window opens on* or *the window faces*. But windows don't point.

Comment: I think that is pretty unusual. I'd prefer 'faces'. "One of the windows in the kitchen faces 5th NE street". EDIT or, as, Peter Shor says 'looks out'.

Comment: @PeterShor "[Point](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/point)" has the same meaning as "face": To face in a particular direction.

Comment: @Rathony: Just because one word has roughly the same meaning as another, it doesn't mean that you can replace one with the other and still have idiomatic English; *"window faces south"* gets nearly 100 hits in Google books, while *"window points south"* gets three (including a duplicate).

Comment: Yeah, "the window faces 5th Street NE" would be a normal way to say it in the US.

Comment: @PeterShor Valid point. But you cannot stop people from using "point" and people are using it. People use "point" figuratively as if their (index) finger was pointing at something. I saw more examples than that.

Comment: @Rathony - But is a usage that is rare (even if occasionally used) what the OP would regard as a "better suggestion"?

Comment: @Ranthony, please show us an example of such usage. I am doubtful.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK If you broaden your search words like "[south-pointing window](http://kstp.com/news/stories/s6646.shtml?cat=17)", you will find more examples. It is a US News site and it doesn't use "south-facing" window. Do you want me to show more examples?

Comment: @Rathony: "south-pointing window": 8 google hits. "south-facing window": over 7000 google hits. And several native English speakers tell you "south-pointing window" sounds odd to them (although the meaning is quite clear). It may be used, but it's quite rare.

Comment: @PeterShor I agree. I changed the order in my answer. Thanks.